# Python requests Session management for an API

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am dealing with an API which has token based session management where token validation occurs at server side. The token has an expiry time.

```
import requests
payload = {"username": username, "password": password}
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
token = response.json()['token']
ses = requests.Session()
ses.cookies.set('_token', token, domain='<domain>', path='/')
```

using above code i am maintaining the session at global level
I had to restart my application again and again to recreate the session,
To deal with that i used the status code check to recreate the session if the status code is 4xx

Is there a better and effective way to handle server side sessions?